# Photoshop Save for web batch not saving the right "Save For Web" size

Tags: adobe-photoshop, batch-processing

I am using Photoshop CS4 Version 11.0.2.  I make an action called Resize to 388px. I record the action as follows:

Start Recording

```
Image
Image Size
Adjust size of image down to 388px.
File
Save for web and devices
I choose JPEG Low
I check Optimized
Hit Save
Direct the save to the "Resized to 388px For Web" folder. 
Save the file in the "Resized to 388px For Web" folder.
Stop recording
```

The size of the resulting jpeg file is 8k and the file dimensions are 388x388

When I run it in batch, the resulting file dimensions are correct, but the file size is much larger at 209k which is the same as when I simply change the file size and use "Save As" manually.

Here is How I run the batch:

```
File
Automate Batch
Source
Folder
Choose (Choose my source folder)
Check off Suppress File Open Options dialogs and Suppress Color Profile Warnings.
Destination
Choose (Choose my destination folder)
ok.
```

Can you explain what I am doing wrong or is this the normal result.

Thanks,

Bruce

Comment: what about resaving as 72dpi though?

Answer (score 1):

I don't immediately see a problem there without testing it, but your simplest solution is to use the Image Processor script that comes with Photoshop and Bridge. I don't recall off-hand, but I'm pretty sure it's been around since CS2.

- Select all the images in Bridge that you want to resize
- Choose `Tools > Photoshop > Image Processor`. Bridge will open Photoshop if it's not already running and run the script, which starts with a dialog box.
- Fill in the dialog with size, destination and any renaming you want to do
- Click OK

You can also run this from inside Photoshop, with the extra step of selecting the images once the script starts running. It's simpler to start in Bridge.